# Make div height Responsive when page is resizing

Tags: css, height, responsive, auto

I have a responsive slider with full-screen images. When I resize the page images stays responsive but the problem I`m running into is that the parent div stays to the original height and I get very big white space and I don`t know a method to fix the issue.
Sorry but i don`t know how to explain this,maybe youy can figure out from the image i added.

```
<!-- !Showcase -->
  <div id="showcase">
    <i id="arrow-left" class="arrow far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left "></i>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2 "></div>
      <div class="slide  slide3"></div>
    </div>
    <i id="arrow-right" class="far arrow fa-arrow-alt-circle-right "></i>
  </div>


#showcase {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#slider {
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background-size: contain !important;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar1.jpg) no-repeat center 10%/cover;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar2.jpg) no-repeat center 10%/cover;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url(/Core/img/lazar3.jpg) no-repeat center 10%/cover;
}
```

Comment: `#showcase`has a fixed height, turn it into a min-height or remove it to allow container fit to its content's height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showcase has a fixed height, turn it into a min-height or remove it to allow the container to fit its content's

Answer (score 0):

As [G-Cyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939795/make-div-height-responsive-when-page-is-resizing#comment98534246_55939795) said in his comment, your container element (#showcase) has an absolute height of 500px. That is what is blocking your element from filling up whenever your content would regularly go above 500px. If you want your baseline height of this container to be at least 500px, change `height: 500px` to `min-height: 500px`. That should work.